# Has org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webflux.SpringWebFluxEngineContext removed from thymeleaf-spring5:3.1.1.RELEASE?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm getting below error when I upgraded thymleaf libraries `org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:3.0.15.RELEASE`, `org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:3.0.4.RELEASE` to `org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring5:3.1.1.RELEASE`, `org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:3.1.1.RELEASE`.

Error Message

`error: cannot find symbol import org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webflux.SpringWebFluxEngineContext; ^ symbol:   class SpringWebFluxEngineContext location: package org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webflux`

I also tried to upgrade to `org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring6:3.1.1.RELEASE, org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6:3.1.1.RELEASE`

But still I do not see that `SpringWebFluxEngineContext` is not found when I import it from `import org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webflux.SpringWebFluxEngineContext;`

It seems that `SpringWebFluxEngineContext` is removed from thymleaf 3.1.1 but I'm not sure what class should I use alternatively.

Can someone help me fixing the error?

Comment: you can use `SpringWebFluxTemplateEngine`

Comment: @muhammedozbilici Can you give me the jar that contains `SpringWebFluxTemplateEngine` ? I searched for thymeleaf-spring5-webflux in maven repository but could not find anything.

Comment: check these links -> https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring5/3.0.11.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/spring5/SpringWebFluxTemplateEngine.html

https://hantsy.github.io/spring-reactive-sample/web/view.html